# Android - custom serialization approach

Tags: android, serialization

I have tried XML/JSON object serialization, but I am thinking of custom serialization. Up to now, I haven't found any solutions, which included XML/JSON solutions. Is it bad way of thinking of implementing serialization on my own? Can I get better results then ready made solutions?

thx

Comment: If you plan to use the serialization for passing objects through to other activities in a Bundle, you should consider using Parceable instead.

Comment: Yea, I know. But now I mean serialization between application and server

Comment: As far as I know Google's `protobuf` works on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think JSON is the best for communicating between client and server.
Look at this for a nice example: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

Comment: When you are talking to it as a "best" do you mean in it in terms of speed? or overalPerformance? Or code readability?

Comment: I think all of the above :) Maybe a bit faster would be Google's Protocol Buffers, but those are not readable. JSON is pretty nice for debugging since you can read it. If you need to compress it you can look into using Google's Zippy library, which is supposed to be fast and pretty efficient.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of custom serialization frameworks already available - `protobuf`, `Kryo`, etc. As far as I know at least `protobuf` should work on Android. Here is a nice overview (not related to Android though) http://tech.puredanger.com/2011/05/27/serialization-comparison/

Comment: Thanks, shame there is no such article for android :-(